# MySQL Server not starting in Windows

Tags: mysql

I installed MySQL using Windows Installer, on running the following command to start the server I got the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqld
2021-01-11T00:31:43.496860Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.22) starting as process 13036
2021-01-11T00:31:43.503435Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2021-01-11T00:31:43.503578Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2021-01-11T00:31:43.503878Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\' (OS errno: 2 - No such file or directory)
2021-01-11T00:31:43.520831Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-01-11T00:31:43.521061Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.22)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

How should I resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following command resolved the problem.

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqld --initialize
```